# Q: What is the workaround for nested for loop error - find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm getting to error 'find() takes no keyword arguments' on the line of code `place = racers.find('td', class_='horse_number').get_text()`

I presume this is due to the nested for loop - is find onto find the problem??

My goal is to get detail of the race in first loop, second loop reiterate over each runner within the race, third for loop to get the times that meet each nested if statement.

```
            for race in results:

                race_number = race.find('td', class_='raceNumber').get_text()
                

                race_name1 = race.find('td', class_='raceTitle').get_text()
                
                race_title1 = race.find('td', class_='raceInformation').get_text()
                race_title1 = ' '.join(race_title1.split())
                
                race_distance1 = race.find('td', class_='distance').get_text()

                tableofdata = race.find('table', class_='raceFieldTable')
                
                for racers in tableofdata:

                    place = racers.find('td', class_='horse_number').get_text()
                    

                    horsename = racers.find('a', class_='horse_name_link')
                    horsename = horsename.text.replace('HorseName: ', '') if horsename else ''
                
                    prizemoney = racers.find('td', class_='prizemoney')
                    prizemoney = prizemoney.text.replace('Prizemoney: ', '') if prizemoney else ''
                
                    barrier = racers.find('td', class_='barrier')
                    barrier = barrier.text.replace('Row: ', '') if barrier else ''
                
                    #tabnumber = race.find('td', class_='horse_number')
                    #tabnumber = tabnumber.text.replace('HorseNumber: ', '') if tabnumber else ''
                    #print(tabnumber, tr2)
                    trainer = racers.find_all('td', class_='trainer-short')
                    trainer = trainer.text.replace('Trainer: ', '') if trainer else ''
                
                    driver = racers.find_all('td', class_='driver-short')
                    driver = driver.text.replace('Driver: ', '') if driver else ''
                
                    margin = racers.find_all('td', class_='margin') 
                    margin = margin.text.replace('Margin: ', '') if margin else ''
                
                    startingprice = racers.find_all('td', class_='starting_price')
                    startingprice = startingprice.text.replace('StartingOdds: ', '') 
                    startingprice = startingprice.replace('Â', ' ')if startingprice else ''

                    stewardscomments = racers.find_all('span', class_='stewardsTooltip')
                    stewardscomments = stewardscomments.text.replace('StewardsComments: ', '') if horsename else ''
                
                    scratchingnumber = racers.find_all('td', class_='number')
                    scratchingnumber = scratchingnumber.text.replace('Scratching: ', '') if scratchingnumber else ''
                    tableoftimes = race.find('table', class_='raceTimes')
                
                    for row in tableoftimes.select('td>strong:contains(":")'):
                            for t in row: 
                                if "Track Rating:" in t:
                                    trackrating = t.next_element.strip()
                                else:
                                    trackrating = ''
                                    if "Gross Time:" in t:
                                        grosstime = t.next_element.strip()
                                    else:
                                        grosstime = ''
                                        if "Mile Rate:" in t:
                                            milerate = t.next_element.strip()
                                        else:
                                            milerate = ''
                                            if "Lead Time:" in t:
                                                leadtime = t.next_element.strip()
                                            else:
                                                leadtime = ''
                                                if "First Quarter:" in t:
                                                    firstquarter = t.next_element.strip()
                                                else:
                                                    firstquarter = ''
                                                    if "Second Quarter:" in t:
                                                        secondquarter = t.next_element.strip()
                                                    else:
                                                        secondquarter = ''
                                                        if "Third Quarter:" in t:
                                                            thirdquarter = t.next_element.strip()
                                                        else:
                                                            thirdquarter = ''
                                                            if "Fourth Quarter:" in t:
                                                                fourthquarter = t.next_element.strip()
                                                            else:
                                                                fourthquarter = ''
```

Last query is this replace doesnt work - still prints $2.40Â onto csv file

```
file = open('harnessresults.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8')
writer = csv.writer(file)
....
startingprice = startingprice.replace('Â', ' ')if startingprice else ''
....
writer.writerow([tr2, race_number, race_name1, race_title1, race_distance1, place, horsename, prizemoney, barrier, trainer, driver, margin, startingprice, stewardscomments, scratchingnumber, trackrating, grosstime, milerate, leadtime, firstquarter, secondquarter, thirdquarter, fourthquarter])
```

UPDATED

Start of HTML with **scraping** looks like below

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import requests
import re
import csv
import os
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

file = open('harnessresults.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8')
writer = csv.writer(file)

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate="
base1_url = "http://www.harness.org.au"

webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate=')

soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")

format = "%d-%m-%y"
delta = timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

enddate = datetime(2020, 4, 20)
#prints header in csv
writer.writerow(['Venue', 'RaceNumber', 'RaceName', 'RaceTitle', 'RaceDistance', 'Place', 'HorseName', 'Prizemoney', 'Row', 'Trainer', 'Driver', 'Margin', 'StartingOdds', 'StewardsComments', 'Scratching', 'TrackRating', 'Gross_Time', 'Mile_Rate', 'Lead_Time', 'First_Quarter', 'Second_Quarter', 'Third_Quarter', 'Fourth_Quarter'])


while enddate <= yesterday:
    enddate += timedelta(days=1)
    enddate1 = enddate.strftime("%d-%m-%y") 
    new_url = base_url + str(enddate1)
    soup12 = requests.get(new_url)
    soup1 = bs(soup12.content, "html.parser") 
    table1 = soup1.find('table', class_='meetingListFull')
    
    tr = table1.find_all('tr', {'class':['odd', 'even']})
    
    for tr1 in tr:
        tr2 = tr1.find('a').get_text()
        tr3 = tr1.find('a')['href']
        newurl = base1_url + tr3
        with requests.Session() as s:
            webpage_response = s.get(newurl)
            soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
            #soup1 = soup.select('.content')
            results = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'forPrint'})
            #resultsv2 = soup.find_all('table', {'class':'raceFieldTable'})
```

Expect the CSV to look like

[image]

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Is this a public facing URL? If so, might be easier to post it because we can what your trying to scrape :)

Comment: I've updated scrapping side of HTML to have a look.

Comment: What sort of expected output are you trying to get in your CSV? First couple of lines should be good enough.

Comment: I have fixed that up now @RoadRunner